# Register Script in Plugin Widget

Tags: plugins, widgets, scripts

I need to load a separate js file into a widget and just can't get it to work. So far I have

```
if ( is_active_widget( false, false, $this->id_base, true ) ) {
    function tab_widget_scripts() {
        wp_register_script( 'tabs', plugins_url( 'tabs.js', __FILE__ ), array(), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs.js' );
    }
}
```

in my `function __construct()` and then

```
do_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'tab_widget_scripts' );
```

inside `public function widget( $args, $instance )`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: this WP codex has many examples. See if it points you in the right direction: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 issues.

Firstly, you're calling `do_action`,  triggering the action:

```
do_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'tab_widget_scripts' );
```

When actually, you want to add your function to it, not trigger it. You should be doing this:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'tab_widget_scripts' );
```

Secondly, you're registering this script:

```
tabs
```

Then enqueuing this script:

```
tabs.js
```

Clearly they don't match, in the same way that if I give you the ingredients for cake then tell you to make a latte, it isn't going to work.

Thirdly, you only define the function if the widget is shown on the frontend. This is a little odd, instead you should use `add_action` on your function in your widget class, and always define it, saving yourself an unnecessary call to `is_active_widget`

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's a great explanation and all sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

`do_action` should be `add_action` - you're adding a function to the queue, not executing all functions hooked to the action. That said, you don't have to hook a separate function, you can just enqueue directly in the widget function if you want.

Comment: Thanks Milo, that's a lot more simple than what I was trying.